# flutter stripe_android:verifyReleaseResources'. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks > Android resource linking failed

Tags: flutter, gradle, colors, background, stripe-payments

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_background_dark not found.

```
 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_error_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:5: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_error_container_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:6: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_surface_light not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:7: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_primary_light not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:8: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_surface_light not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:9: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_background_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_error_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_error_container_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:12: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_primary_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:13: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_primary_container_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_secondary_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_secondary_container_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_surface_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_surface_variant_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:18: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_tertiary_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_on_tertiary_container_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:20: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_outline_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:21: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_outline_variant_dark not found.

 ERROR:/Users/mac/StudioProjects/cabme_driver_paid/build/stripe_android/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:22: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_primary_dark not found.
```

flutter_stripe: ^10.1.1 didn't work

Comment: That looks very similar to this bug: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/1676

Have you raised this on `flutter_stripe`'s GH Issues page?